# What causes this tiny font in GUI (High DPI settings enabled)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-10, dpi, hidpi

I have developed an application what - for one user - shows a tiny font size:

[image]

The title bar is not affected by this strange behaviour.

The menustrip and the tab control however is.

I don't play with the font at all. 
I've tried different DPI settings in a sandbox, and for me, this effect never occured.

The user runs his monitor at 1920-1080 (recommended).
He has an Hi DPI monitor.

DPI is at 100%.

No accessibility settings applied.

This reminds me of a situation I had with an Ultra-HD monitor, but I don't remember how I overcame the problem.

Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does that user have any windows accessibility settings changed?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. Windows 10, WinForms. Don't know about accessibility settings. Might be.

Comment: @soohoonigan I have more info now and added it to my post.